# Yesod modify and delete by JSON

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

I'm new in Yesod Haskell, I like it a lot, but I have to leave it after a month because I can not solve this problem: 
I have the version yesod-core version:1.0.1.3
I followed this example:
[More Client Side Yesod: todo sample](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/04/yesod-js-todo)
I can create my own page and populate it with the data via json
After I add a new record using json
But I can not delete or change a record because I can not find a way to bring back the key.
I can not use this system to derive the data as explained here: [Parsing a JSON post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822171/parsing-a-json-post) and 
[Correct way to do a “join” in persist with yesod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779253/correct-way-to-do-a-join-in-persist-with-yesod) and [aeson-0.6.0.2: Fast JSON parsing and encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/latest/doc/html/Data-Aeson-TH.html) Because I always get this error:

```
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  Data.Aeson.TH.withType: Unsupported type: TySynD Model.Elarticoli [] (AppT (ConT Model.ElarticoliGeneric) (ConT Database.MongoDB.Query.Action))
  Code: deriveFromJSON (id) ''Elarticoli
```

If I use this system:

```
Elarticoli
   marca         Text
   descrizione   Text
   idum          Int
   prezzo        Double

instance FromJSON (Key id Elarticoli) where
    parseJSON = fmap Key . parseJSON

instance FromJSON Elarticoli where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Elarticoli
                   <$> v .: "marca"
                   <*> v .: "descrizione"
                   <*> v .: "idum"
                   <*> v .: "prezzo"
parseJSON           _  = fail "Invalid Elarticoli"

postAeldatidelR :: Handler ()
postAeldatidelR = do
    id <- parseJsonBody_
    runDB (delete id)
    sendResponseStatus status204 ()
```

I always get this error:

```
Handler/Aeldati.hs:72:12:
    Ambiguous type variable `val0' in the constraint:
      (PersistEntity val0) arising from a use of `delete'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `runDB', namely `(delete id)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: runDB (delete id)
    In the expression:
      do { id <- parseJsonBody_;
           runDB (delete id);
          sendResponseStatus status204 () }
```

For persistence I use MongoDB.
I'll have to go back to work in Java? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no way for GHC to know the type of `id` in your `postAeldatidelR` function. `parseJsonBody_` says it must be an instance of `FromJSON`. `delete` says it must be an instance of `PersistEntity`. But there are potentially hundreds of instances that could match that.

In times like this, the simplest solution is to provide an explicit type signature. Perhaps this would work:

`haskell
runDB (delete (id :: ElarticoliId))`